# Regexs in Ruby getting filename

Tags: ruby, regex

i am extracting file names of html files using line:

```
filename = File.basename(input_filename, ".*")
```

which currently prints full file name excluding .html extension

All files are stored in the form of `http^x.x.edu^1^2` all file names begin with `http^` and contain `edu^` what i want is to extract **2** (which changes) but it is always the second element after `.edu`. I have attempted destructive `gsub!` but i m weak with regular expressions.

Comment: Could you give a little bit more clear example of what your input string and what you are trying to extract from it?

Comment: Also, could you include the code you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, assuming your input is called `filename`:

```
base_file = filename.gsub(/(\S)*.edu/, '').scan(/\w+/)[1]
```

The `.gsub(/(\S)*.edu, '')` removes everything up to the first slash after TLD (.edu).

Then we scan through what's left (`/some/other/file.html`) using the `/\w+/` regex which results in `['some','other','file','html']`. Selecting the second element (`[1]`) of the scan gives us the second element after the .edu TLD.

It's not pretty but it should get the job done - I'd love to see a more elegant way to do it if anyone has any ideas!

Comment: Good solution it does work, however i found filename.split("^")[4] to be a better solution. Thanks

Comment: Ha! Yes that is a simpler solution. You just had to throw in the remark about a regex in the question and blinded us all to it :)

Answer (score 0):

An example input string would help, but assuming I understand the url structure, you dont need a regex at all:

```
require 'uri'
File.basename(URI.parse('http://subdomain.domain.edu/one/two').path)

=> 'two'
```

Comment: http_^^subdomain.domain.edu^same^different1^continue^continue^continue <=extract different1 
http_^^subdomain2.domain.edu^same^notsame^continue^continue2^continue5 <=extract notsame 
http_^^subdomain.domain.edu^different^somethingelse^continue^continue^continue <=extract somethingelse 
http_^^subdomain3.domain.edu^different^whatsiit^continue^differnt^<=extract whatsiit **Extract every second element after .edu 1^2^<= are always changing**